# Write to kubernetes redis cluster with 3 masters and 3 slaves

Tags: c#, kubernetes, asp.net-core-2.1, stackexchange.redis, redis-cluster

I follow https://github.com/sanderploegsma/redis-cluster to run redis cluster on AWS EKS. This ends up with one `Service` and 6 `Pod`s with 3 masters and 3 slaves. How does the C# client find out the master redis cluster node in order to write to the cache? Thanks.